# Applying XSLT to XML in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt

I'm returning XML from a controller Action by using a custom ActionResult:

```
    public class XmlActionResult : ActionResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is a custom ActionResult that outputs the content of an XML document to the response stream
    /// </summary>

    private readonly XDocument _document;
    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    public XmlActionResult(XDocument document)
    {
        _document = document;
        MimeType = "text/xml";
        Formatting = Formatting.None;

    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
       context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
       context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = MimeType;

       using(var writer = new XmlTextWriter(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, null)
           {
               Formatting = Formatting

           })

        _document.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

This outputs the XML tree to the browser. I have an XSL file that transforms the XML, how would I apply the stylesheet to the XML output?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: That is a fair point, apologies!

Comment: Where do you want to apply the XSLT transformation -- on the server, or on the client browser?

Answer (score 0):

[Use `XslCompiledTransform` to apply any XSLT 1.0 stylesheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4.aspx) or use third party XSLT 2.0 processors like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime to apply any XSLT 2.0 stylesheet.

You can pass in your XDocument as the first argument of the `Transform` method of `XslCompiledTransform` by calling the extension method `CreateNavigator` on it e.g.

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
proc.Load("sheet.xsl");
poc.Transform(_document.CreateNavigator(), null, context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
```

To use the extension method you need a `using System.Xml.XPath;` directive. And depending on the transformation result (e.g. whether it is HTML for the content type text/html or XHTML for the content type application/xhtml+xml or some other format) you might want to change the ContentType you send to the browser so that the transformation result is parsed and rendered appropriately.